# doctrine storing the resultset?

Tags: php, doctrine

I'm new to doctrine and I'm running into a problem. Here it is:

I have the following model/entity:

```
<?php
namespace models;

/** @Entity @Table(name="teams") @HasLifecycleCallbacks */
class Team
{

...

/** @OneToMany(targetEntity="Teammember", mappedBy="team") */
private $members;

...

function getTeamsILeadForGame($user, $game)
{
    $q = $this->doctrine->em->createQuery("SELECT t, tm FROM models\Team t JOIN t.members tm WHERE tm.user = ?1 AND t.game = ?2 AND tm.is_leader = ?3 ORDER BY t.name ASC");
    $q->setParameter(1, $user);
    $q->setParameter(2, $game);
    $q->setParameter(3, 1);

    try {
        return $q->getResult();
    } catch (\Doctrine\ORM\NoResultException $e) {
        return null;
    }
}
}
```

AS you can see, there is a link to the Teammember entity. In the function I wrote, I'm trying to get all the teams where the current user has the is_leader flag set to 1.

This query executes just fine and the result is what I expect it to be.

Now onto the problem. Further down in my controller I try to do the following:

$postteam = $this->em->find('models\Team', $this->input->post('team'));

The team data it returns is correct, but when I call $postteam->getMembers() it just returns 1 row (the one where is_leader = 1) instead of all the members of that team.

So it seems like doctrine is keeping my other function in the back of its head? I'm really confused as to why this is.

So like I said, my controller looks like this:

```
$teams = models\Team::getTeamsILeadForGame($this->user->getId(), $tournament->getGame()->getId());

// Do some checks on the returned teams

$postteam = $this->em->find('models\Team', $this->input->post('team'));
$postteam->getMembers();
```

When I remove the $teams = models....... line, everything works fine again. So it seems to me like doctrine filters its internal resultset by that line, and then only searches in that resultset from then on.

Any ideas on how to fix this? Thnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out finaly :D

It turns out it had to do with lazy loading. Once I set 'fetch=eager' at the link towards the members, everything worked fine.

Hope this is of any help for people having the same problem...